# Graph $G$ that does not contain a loop contains a bipartite spanning subgraph $H$, such that for any vertex $v$, there is $d_H(v)\ge\frac{1}{2}d_G(v)$

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

How do you prove that for any graph $G$ that does not contain a loop* contains a bipartite spanning subgraph $H$, such that for any vertex $v$, there is $d_H(v)\ge\frac{1}{2}d_G(v)$?

<sup>* A loop is defined as an edge whose both endpoints are the same vertex. Graph $G$ may contain repeated edges.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Just take the bipartite subgraph with maximum number of edges.

Comment: I didn't quite get it.

Comment: @iBug Supose $H$ is a bipartite subgraph with the maximum possible number of edges; you want to show that $d_H(v)\ge\frac12d_G(v).$ In other words, you want to show that $v$ has at least as many neighbors on the other side of the bipartition as on its own side. Assume for a contradiction that $v$ has **more** neighbors on its own side. Can you think of a way to modify $H$ and get a bipartite subgraph with **more** edges, contradicting the assumption that $H$ was maximal? What would happen if you just moved $v$ to the other side?

Comment: @bof Ah very clear now! Thanks for the extended hint!

Comment: @iBug Actually the way I phrased my hint only makes sense for graphs without repeated edges. In the general case you have to count edges instead of vertices, but the idea is the same. But I suppose you figured that out.

Comment: @bof Yes I know. Counting yhe edges instead of vertices.